# Multiple SPF domains in SPF DNS record. To MX or not MX?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, microsoft-office-365

My understanding of SPF records is that you don’t create two separate ones, but that you include multiple domains in one record with multiple include statements.

My company's existing SPF record as required by Office 365 does not have MX at the start. Now I need to add a second Adobe domain that we will be using for an email campaign, and Adobe say that I should use:

`v=spf1 mx include:worldsecuresystems.com ~all` or if I already have an SPF record:

`include:worldsecuresystems.com`

What would be difference between me having `MX` present or not?

i.e.

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:worldsecuresystems.com –all
```

or

```
v=spf1 mx include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:worldsecuresystems.com –all
```

What MS say:

[image: Microsoft's suggested Office 365 DNS Settings]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't already have an SPF record they are suggesting the following:

```
v=spf1 mx include:worldsecuresystems.com ~all
```

They are basically guessing that you send outbound email from the servers present in your domains MX records. They can't guarantee this so also suggest `~all` (instead of `-all`) as this shouldn't cause your outbound email to be explicitly blocked if it doesn't come from them or your MX servers.

If you already have an SPF record then obviously they are just suggesting that you modify your existing SPF record to add their entry in (`include:worldsecuresystems.com`). Obviously they expect that if you already have an SPF record, it will already contain any other servers that you sent email from.

At the end of the day, you should add `mx` if you are sending outbound email from the servers listed in the MX record for your domain. If you do not send email from these servers, or have any servers you do send email from listed separately you don't need the `mx` entry.

The inlusion of `mx` will not effect Adobe, all the servers they will be sending from will be covered by the include statement.

Comment: Thanks. So how come Microsoft didn't advise us to use MX in their SPF record for Office 365? And should I use - or ~ ? Still a bit confused.

Comment: I'd have to see the exact wording from Microsoft's instructions, but it sounds like Microsoft give you the entries you need to *add* to your SPF record and either assume that you are using their service exclusively or if you're not, that you'll realize you need to add your own outbound servers to the record as well (or just keep you existing entries and add theirs if you already have an SPF record)

Comment: If you don't already have `mx` in your SPF record and send all outbound email via Adobe or Office365 then I highly doubt you'll need `mx` in there.

Comment: Updated OP to include MS instructions.

Comment: The Microsoft instructions looks like they expect you are *exclusively* using Office365 to send emails from your domain. They allow all Office365 servers (via an include statement) and reject everything else. Not very good really, it doesn't appear to even mention that the record may need to be different if you send from other locations (unless it's somewhere else on that page)

Comment: I think a fair assumption is that since Office365 is a full mail service with both inbound and outbound, ie your `MX` records are supposed to be those specified by Office365, they know you shouldn't need `mx` in SPF. Other services that want to send mail on your behalf do not know what `MX` records you have and try to be careful not to disrupt your normal mail service.